# Every Verb can be gerund or infinitive

Tags: gerunds, infinitive-vs-gerund

There are three things but they are all related to each other.

1)-Is every verb allowed to use as a gerund or infinitive? If a verb has the first form and participle form, it means it can be used as infinitive or gerund?

2|)-Secondly, Every verb doesn't allow to use gerund or infinitive after it. Which dictionary helps or explain either this verb allows the usage of infinitive or gerund?

3)- confusion raises more when you think of cantenative verb. Is every transitive verb a catenative verb? Is there any dictionary dictates the particular types of verb.

Regards;

Comment: Every verb has an infinitival form, of course, and a gerund-participle form. But not all verbs take non-finite clausal complements (some are strongly stative), but those that do are called 'catenative' verbs. It's quite a big topic!

Comment: @bill Yes. (Well, apart from modal verbs. They don't have either. The verb *beware* only has a plain form. The verb *used* doesn't have an *-ing* form and can't be used in a *to*-infinitival construction.)

Comment: @Araucaria Yes, yes! Don't nit-pick! Since the OP's question is about infinitives and gerunds, I was of course referring only to full-blown lexical verbs. Incidentally Wiki gives an _ing_ form for "beware" [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/beware) but I've never encountered it

Comment: The verbs which don't have all the expected forms are called "defective".

Answer (score 1):

Not every verb can be used as a gerund or an infinitive.

A gerund is a verb in its *ing* (present participle) form that functions as a noun that names an activity rather than a person or thing. Any action verb can be made into a gerund.

An infinitive is a verb form that acts as other parts of speech in a sentence. It is formed with *to + base* form of the verb.

Modal verbs (e.g. can, may, must) cannot be used in these ways.

A Google search for just the two keywords "gerund infinitive" returns many pages with information and examples.

Comment: In traditional grammar, there are two _ing_ forms: the present participle and the gerund. But in modern grammar we recognise only one, called the 'gerund-participle'. The important point is that it is a verb, though a few of them can form nouns by conversion (called gerundial nouns) and adjectives (called participial adjectives).

Comment: Auxiliary verbs can have these forms, but *modal* auxiliary verbs cannot.

Comment: @Araucaria Thanks, it looks like I was thinking one thing and wrote something else.

Comment: @Araucaria. Thanks. And is there a dictionary which explains a specific verb can be used as a gerund or infinitive or it accepts or doesn't accept non-infinitive arguments.